# su command wont allow PW entry

Tags: password, su

I tried to get some files from a damaged Ubuntu OS on an USB stick using `su` in terminal and terminal wouldn't let me enter the password or type anything at all

Comment: what did it out put and why are you not using sudo

Comment: well apparently as a security precaution in terminal on ubuntu 21.04 hirschute hippo there is no indication that a proper password was entered. after entering sudo command it asks for a password. i enter my password. nothing happens no sign that anything was entered and after 20 minutes only blinky cursor

Comment: @lolo That sounds more like the command was started successfully by sudo, but has gotten hung up. Are you able to mount the drive of your system if you boot from a live USB?

Comment: yes i can boot from a live cd. i am actually trying to get some files from an os that has a corrupted fs. both of the os are ubuntu 21.04 hirschute hippo one is on an sd and the other is on a usb2.0 flash. i was trying to get my files from the sd. it mounts and i can access the files except the root and the swap file.

Comment: i appreciate your input, and thank you. im just going to watch some more tutorials i think i simply missed a lesson somewhere.

Comment: Let me get this strate so on the last install of Ubuntu there was list file n in the root directory and when you try to get it say permission denied you tried sudo and get this `[sudo] password for lolo:` and nothing else if that is so sudo is working try `sudo id` and if you get `[sudo] password for lolo:`  and `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)` it works